# In MS chart, #PERCENT{N} keyword will not return only a numeric value without decimal

Tags: c#, mschart, pie-chart, dynamic-controls

am using Ms chart and i just need a number or numeric value for percentage calculation so for that am using #PERCENT{N} but its returning a decimal value like 0.45 0.78 0.11 etc.. which i do not need, i want it should give me like only numeric value like 45 78 11 23 etc.. please see my below code. its just a part of my coding am posting here. please help me out.

```
LegendCellColumn PercentageColumn = new LegendCellColumn();
PercentageColumn.Text = "#PERCENT{N}";
PercentageColumn.HeaderText = "%";
PercentageColumn.Name = "Percentage %";
//avgColumn.HeaderBackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
Chart1.Legends[0].CellColumns.Add(PercentageColumn);
```

What should i make with this to get only numeric value with out decimal value.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Decimal outDec;
if (Decimal.TryParse("<some string>", out outDec))
{
    // Sets Decimal as a Percentage out of 100
    PercentageColumn.Text = Convert.ToInt32(outDec * 100).ToString();
}
```

**Edit**

To do it specifically using `String` formatting :

```
PercentageColumn.Text = "#PERCENT{P0}";
```

From: [Social.MSDN - Shows Percentages on Pie Chart ( Aspnet)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/thread/74d5f11d-e8f0-4767-b2ca-45beadde4c40/)
and
[MSDN - Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: Yes Thank you very much its showing me the Results as How i expected.  Just for information :  If we use "#PERCENT{P0}" the results will be just numbers like 10% 23% 74% etc.. If we use "#PERCENT{P}" the results will be exactly and more accurate like 10.93% 21.96% etc.. If we use "#PERCENT{N}" the results will be 0.10% 0.21% 0.74% etc.. Thanks

Comment: @Rakesh Good feedback. The link to MSDN - Standard Numeric Format Strings above goes into additional details on how to use this and more.